# How can i select random items from a set of two lists and then remove that set of items from another list built out of all the possibilities

Tags: python, list

Working on a card game for an assignment.  I have three lists here, and I am trying to figure out how I can ensure that a card doesn't show up in the deck list if it is in one of the hands.

```
DECK = []
PLAYER = []
COMP = []
for x in PLAYER:
    if i,j in PLAYER:
        if i,j in DECK:
            p = DECK.index(i,j)
            p = -51+p
            DECK.pop(-p)
```

I am aware that i,j does not work here.  How can I represent the card in the hand so that I can index and remove it from the list that contains the deck?  I think I'm probably way off on this stuff, I've only been learning Python for about four weeks now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider building your deck and hand objects such that it's impossible to arrive in this sort of situation. If you want to actually do set operations (difference, union, whatever) look at the `set` builtin data type.

Comment: the 'DECK' list is built using two other lists, one for suit names and one for rank names.  I believe these are called tuples?  At this point in my code there are five cards in each of 'PLAYER', 'COMP', and I am trying to remove those ten cards from 'DECK'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
for x in PLAYER:
    if x in DECK:
        DECK.remove(x)
```

Comment: I was making it way more complicated, I see that now.  This is much simpler.  Sometimes I become so narrowed in my focus.

Answer (score 0):

You should hand out cards from DECK to PLAYER and COMP. In that case, you wouldn't end up in such a situation.

Something like:

```
PLAYER.append(DECK.pop(index))
```